# What structure or mechanism can I use to generate a LaTeX interpreter?

Tags: latex, interpreter, automaton

What I am trying to do, is an interpreter that receives as input a pure *LaTeX* file, and returns a string "in English".
For example.

Input:

```
$$ sum _ {i} = 0} ^ 3 \ frac {i} {3} $$
```

Output:

Sum from i equal to zero to three, from "i" divided by three.

Input:

```
$ e ^ {i \ pi} + 1 = 0 $
```

Output:
e raised to the power of i times pi, plus one equal to zero

I thought the solution could be an FDA, but I realized that the code would be really extensive and laborious.

Is there a better technique or algorithm to do this? Thanks.

P.D I'm not sure if this is the right section to ask this, if isn't, please tell me.

Comment: The talks from last years TeX user group meeting might be interesting for you, see the ones on the first afternoon about accessible pdf with math: https://tug.org/tug2018/program.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by FDA (perhaps deterministic finite automaton?) but in any event, you could probably do this by writing a context-free grammar for your expressions, compiling this into a parser, running inputs through to get the parse tree, and then writing a method that does an inorder traversal of the parse tree and outputs the English version of everything along the way. As a super lazy example:

```
<line> := $$ <expr> $$
<expr> := sum _ {<token>} = <expr>} ^ <expr> \ <expr>
<expr> := frac {<expr>} {<expr>}
<expr> := <token>
<token> := i | 0 | 1 | 3
```

Then your expression would parse as

```
  __________<line>__________
 /            |             \
$$          <expr>          $$
     _________|_________________________________________________
    /         |         |        |        |        |       |    \
sum _ {     <token>    } =     <expr>    } ^     <expr>    \    <expr>
           /                   /                /                 |
          i             <token>          <token>                  |
                       /                /                         |
                      0                3                          |
     _____________________________________________________________/
    /       |        |       |       |
frac {    <expr>    } {    <expr>    }
            |                |
          <token>          <token>
            |                |
            i                3
```

The way to process this would then be to define a semantics for the language which is almost a mapping from one language to another. The semantics will keep track of the current context in the tree in terms of what derivations we made and use that to determine the translation. So:

```
<line>: setting line context
 $$: has no meaning in line context
 <expr>: setting expression context
  sum _ {: emit "sum of" and enter sum context
   <token>: enter token context
    i: emit "i"
   } =: emit "from"
   <expr>: enter expression context
    <token>: enter token context
     0: emit "0"
   } ^: emit "to"
   <expr>: enter expression context
    <token>: enter token context
     3: emit "3"
   \: emit "of" in sum context
   <expr>: enter expression context
    frac {: enter frac expr context
    <expr>: enter expression context
     <token>: enter token context
      i: emit "i"
    } {: emit "over"
    <expr>: enter expression context
     <token>: enter token context
      3: emit "3"
    }: has no meaning in frac expr context
```

The trick is getting the entering/exiting contexts right. It seems to me that you can massage your grammar so that nonterminals correspond directly to contexts, and that would make it easy.